# How to Disable Reserved Storage on other drives in windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have a fresh installation of windows 11 pro on my laptop SSD and also have a 3 partition HDD. I am running out of space really hard and I checked the setting for some help and look what I found, windows is using 23GB of Drive E for System & reserved.

Here is a screenshot of the storage setting of drive E:

[image: screenshot of the storage setting of drive E]

I don't want this feature on my other drives and I searched for some solutions for disabling this feature! but there is a command for disabling this only for drive C. this is the command

```
DISM /Online /Set-ReservedStorageState /State:Disabled
```

what can I do to free up this space?

Comment: That is not reserved. You are seeing System Storage because you have Apps and Features on another drive. That is all you are seeing.

Comment: but all i have on that partition is videos and Docs. also when I check the properties of all files and folders in that drive, the on disk size is not the same as the properties of the partition, and the difference is 23GB.

Answer (score 0):

"System & reserved" is a very vague term that may include various
types of disk data.

To free disk-space, the first step should be Disk Clean-up,
found in Explorer when doing right-click on the disk E and selecting
Properties. The "Disk Clean-up" button is found inside the General tab.
Select as many items to clean out as possible and click OK.
When cleanup is finished, repeat it again.

Another possibility is a huge search index : Run
*Start > Indexing Options*, remove unwanted folders and press Rebuild.

You could also empty the Recycle Bin to save some space.

Last, you could use program such as
[TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free)
or
[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/)
to look for large folders that could be pruned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have exactly the same problem but with much more lost space:

An external 4TB SSD NTFS-formatted, 3.63TB free as usual. I copy 2.6TB of documents and it is full. Checking through teh Windows 11 "storage usage"  settings shows that there is 1TB in "System & reserved". In there it only shows 1TB as "System files" with no options to do something.

TreeSize shows 0 bytes in Recycle or System Volume Info. No hidden files. No other stuff.
New installation of Windows 11 Enterprise. No special software was installed. No special settings.
The external drive is not marked for Indexing. One Basic data partition. Bitlocker is off.

After one hour it seems that Windows released 180GB of the reserved space (the "System files" dropped to 825GB). Is there a mechanism, an option, or a registry hack that switches off this reserved storage? If a drive is only used for data, there is no need to keep space. And 1TB of space on an SSD is VERY expensive.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1172264)

Comment: I thought I gave an answer by saying that I had the same problem and Windows automatically released the reserved space after some time. On the other hand, the previous answer provided is not even relevant to the initial question.

Comment: Sorry, that is not clear to me.  Especially since you ask another question inside your answer.  Then I am left wondering if is this an answer or a question.